# How to print content of $2 after "\"

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script named "test.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "sed -i '/$1/c\$2' $3"
```

Running as: `./test.sh "This line is removed." "some text here" out.txt` . I want this to be printed **exactly**:

```
sed -i '/This line is removed./c\some text here' out.txt
```

Output is printing as:

```
sed -i '/This line is removed./c$2' out.txt
```

The problem is there with `\$` it is printing `$` not allowing content of `$2`. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line in your script with double slash:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "sed -i '/$1/c\\$2' $3"
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
echo "sed -i '/$1/c\\$2' $3"
```

Comment: Just 6 seconds late :)